# Android Studio Log In - Authentication/Database

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering which one would be better, Authentication with Firebase or a database in Firebase. This is the general idea of my project, and I was wondering which one would be best:

I am creating an companion to a game, and this app can be registered to users, or a Clan which is a group of users. I need to group the users into their clans if they choose to do so, so I am guessing the database is better. But, Firebase Authentication seems like an easier process. Is a database better? Also, users will register online with my website, so it can be easier without a register process in-app.

Thank you for reading my post and hopefully for answering it!

-Braythor

Answer (score 0):

You can have users Register/Login using the Firebase Authentication and when they do that you add their username to the database to be able to the group them by clan under different nodes in firebase.

Not sure if this is what you were asking, but you're right that using Firebase Authentication to have users register is easy, so this implementation would allow you to do that while also grouping them by clan in the database.